# ViewDidLoad invocation order in a parent-child relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, containers

In my iOS project, which uses storyboard, the first viewController has a container view linked by an embedded segue to a childViewController.
I noticed that `viewDidLoad:` is called on child before than on his parent.

The whole sequence is:

`initWithCoder:` on viewController

`initWithCoder:` on childViewController

`prepareForSegue:` on viewController

`viewDidLoad` on childViewController (at this point childViewController.parentViewController return no object)

`viewDidLoad` on viewController (at this point viewController.childViewControllers[0] returns the childViewController)

I have never noticed this behaviour before, so I ask your opinion about the best practice to initialise the viewController environment before the childViewController, should I exploit the implementation of prepareForSegue: even if I haven't any data to pass to the child?

Comment: It is very likely you might have accessed `.view` property of the child view controller before you add it to the controller hierarchy. Maybe you've changed the background color of child view somewhere in your code before you call `.addChildViewController()`? You might want to print `childViewController.isViewLoaded` to find out what exactly caused the view to be loaded.

Comment: I prepared an example you can download here https://github.com/enricocupellini/containerChild , can you verify the same order I said by add breakpoints ?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called after a controller's view has been loaded with loadView(). Since a custom container VC has the child container VC embedded, the child container VC must also be loaded in the process of loading the container's view. That's why for container VCs `viewDidLoad` of the child VC is called before `viewDidLoad` of the parent (unlike for NavigationController for instance)

It doesn't seem like you can use `prepare(for:)` to pass data to the embedded VC, since it is called even before any of the parent's or the children's viewDidLoad is called

Comment: yes I think you are right